# Matlab finding neighbors from a list of coordinates

Tags: arrays, matlab, nearest-neighbor, neighbours

I have an array of n-elements by m-properties.
id1 x1 y1
id2 x2 y2
...
idn xn yn

I have a coordinate (x,y) and I want to find all the ids of elements which are to the immediate left, up, bottom and down of (x,y), that means
(x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x+1,y), (x, y-1).

How can I do this in a fast way?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some code if you can. Also, are you assuming your array is 'periodic'? I other words, is (x,x1) connected with (x,xn)?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with that? (store the values, find the max, do some calculation, etc),  there are several ways to treat the nearest neighbors of an element in a matrix in an efficient way...

Answer (score 0):

Say that the coordinates (except the one of interest) are located in X (1 x n) and Y (1 x n).

1 - Calculate the Euclidean distance to all coordinates:

```
D = sqrt((X - x).^2 + (Y - y).^2));
```

2 - Sort the Distance vector D to find the 4 coordinates whose Euclidean distance is minimum

```
[M idx] = sort(D);
```

3- Get the coordinates of the nearest points

```
X(idx(1:4))
Y(idx(1:4))
```

Check if it works...

Answer (score 0):

@ Oliver:
I believe that it won't work since you mag get all the neighbours in the same quarter of circle surrounding the interesting point.

In my opinion, a better solution should be one dividing the zone around each interesting points into 4 zones (which differ in dX positive, dX negative, dY positive and dY negative (4 combinations of dX,dY couples). In each zone it is needed to find the minimal euclidian difference.